# How do you instrument a nodepool in AKS to use their public ip for all communication outbound?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, aks

**How do you go about configuring two nodes in AKS to use their public ip in a request/response type setting?**

Say you have two nodes in AKS, **A** and **B**. **A** hosts a API and **B** consumes it. **B** is configured with a public ip. and **A** has a DNS name mapping to it's public loadbalancer. **B** uses the public domain name when resolving API requests.

However upon a API request,  **A** reports that **B**'s ip is it's internal ip, and not it's public ip. Why is that?